# Kubuntu 12.10 laptop battery droping fast

Tags: kubuntu, battery-life, hp-pavilion

I have done fresh install of Kubuntu 12.10 on my HP Pavilion G6 Laptop. I'm a bit nervous that my battery is not lasting more than 1 hour while for Windows 8 it was lasting for 5 Hours(while using MySQL and Wifi)

I have set the brightness to very low has shutdown my bluetooth. But still my battery is not lasting.

Please guide me, how to increase the battery life.

Below are my laptop configuration:

- Intel Core i5-2nd Generation
- 500 GB Hard-disk
- 4 GB Ram
  1 GB - AMD Raedon 7600 HD Graphic Card

Answer (score 0):

As advised on another Stack Exchange forum, the procedure to acomplish an answer to your question would be:

adding the following kernel parameters

```
i915.i915_enable_rc6=1
i915.i915_enable_fbc=1
i915.lvds_downclock=1
pcie_aspm=force
```

plus:

Adding to `/etc/default/grub`, Line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.lvds_downclock=1"`

(remember to `sudo update-grub` after editing)

full credit: https://askubuntu.com/a/83721/124343

note: there is also a great article [here](http://www.totalnetsolutions.net/2012/12/09/lenovo-t430-running-kubuntu-12-10-for-extreme-battery-life/)

Comment: Znau, Thanks for your response. But I am new to Unix Based OS. So, where to add kernel parameters and grub editing. Please tell me the full code/script.